# Is tenant data removed from disk when deleting the tenant?

Tags: weaviate

We need to observe GDPR data privacy laws. When we call client.schema_remove_class_tenants(), we can confirm that a subsequent query does not find the tenants data (trying with the tenant name and with tenant=None).

Question: Upon removing a tenant, is the tenant's data deleted from the database or is it just de-indexed (requiring additional steps for actual removal)?

Weaviate performs as expected, but we are unsure of the actual state of the database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same question, I got the following response from Weaviate support ...

*Tenants in Weaviate are isolated from all the other tenants. Each tenant has its own vector index and inverted index. Deleting one tenant deletes everything associated with it: the vector index, the inverted index and the content of the objects themselves. The process is not reversible because it is an OS level function that deletes everything associated with the tenant and once the request for deletion returns it means everything is already deleted.*

For us, the perfect answer!